# Are spotify apps allowed to stream unlimited music in the same way as SoundCloud apps?

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I have a website(server based application) that has an integration with SoundCloud to allow users to search for and stream music directly from our site. Using libspotify, is it legal to allow our users to stream music in the same way from Spotify, or in order to let users listen to unlimited streams, is the app required to run within the Spotify App Desktop browser?

Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 0):

Your users must have a Spotify account, even if the streams are unlimited and there's no way to avoid that. SoundCloud is really different of Spotify and doesn't have the same philosophy ...